# TempData persisting issue after .Net framework upgradation

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-framework-version

I am facing an issue of TempData after I upgrade Dot Net framework `4.6.1` to `4.7.2`.
TempData is not persisting its value, even though I use `Tempdata.Peek(Keyname)`. Additionally I have placed `TempData.Keep()` as well to double check. Am I missing anything with this up-gradation? Because previously it was working fine.

Any help is appreciated!

**UPDATE**

In my Get() method setting TempData:

```
 TempData["Keyname"] = resultModel;
```

Using TempData value again:

```
var ddlValues = TempData.Peek("Keyname") as MyModel;
//tried this as well
// var ddlValues = (FASAMSMapFieldConfigModel)TempData["MappedFieldConfig"];
```

As I previously mentioned in question keeping its data as well:

```
TempData.Keep();
```

But ddlValues is `null`

Comment: do you call `services.AddMemoryCache();` in Startup.cs ?

Comment: No, there is not such code in this file. Do I need to put this line?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Are you using ASP.NET MVC or .NET Core?

Comment: I was about to inform you that I am using ASP.NET MVC

Comment: My mistake. Can you share some code of how you save and read data from TempData?

Comment: @Catalin  Updated.

Comment: First thing you should try is to save a primitive type or a string in the TempData, to make sure you don't have any serialization problems with the `resultModel`

Comment: I tried the same by setting string data. But it did not help.

Comment: Can you post a complete example of your Controller? it might be something wrong there